# Can Jacobi's formulation of Maupertuis' principle be derived in Riemannian geometry?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, variational-principle

I want to  arrive to Hamilton-Jacobi equation using the Riemannian geometry.

So let $\textbf{X}\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, where $M$ is Riemannian manifold whose metric is $g:\textbf{T}M \times \textbf{T}M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, let suppose that $\textbf{X}=grad f$.

So $$g(\textbf{X},\textbf{X})=g(g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{j}},g^{\mu \nu}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\nu}})=g^{ij}g^{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}g(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{j}},\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\nu}})=g^{ij}g_{j\nu}g^{\nu\mu}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}.$$

Finally, we get that: $g(\textbf{X},\textbf{X})=g^{i\mu}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}$.

Until here it is more or less the things that i know . The function that i defined before it is a lagrangian of free particle $$L=\frac{1}{2}g_{ij}\dot x^{i}\dot x^{j},$$ so we now that the curves of this lagrangian $x^{k}(t)$ are geodesic that is $\nabla_{\dot x^{k}}\dot x^{k}=0$. I do not know to prove with this information that $g(\textbf{X},\textbf{X})$ is a constant, where $\textbf{X}$ is the vector field generated by $L$

Finallly, i have another question of Jacobi's Principle. Let $H\in C^{\infty}(\textbf{T}^{*}M) $ be a hamiltonian function of the form $$H=\frac{1}{2}g^{ij}p_{i}p_{j}+V$$ where $g$ is the metric of the riemaniann manifold and $V$ is the potential function $V:M\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The jacobi's principle said that the curves in $M$ are geodesic of metric $$(E-V)g_{ij}dx^{i}\otimes dx^{j}$$
and the new hamiltonian is
$$h=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{g^{ij}}{E-V})p_{i}p_{j}.$$
Again, the solution of the curves here are geodesic, but  some of the properties of the geodesic are that the tangent curves are parallel to the curve and the aceleration is 0 so, if it is a potential, there is an aceleration. My questions are this geodeisc lies in a new manifold $M_{2}?$ If it is like this how can arrive to the original manifold?

Answer (score 0):

In a non-relativistic context the metric becomes like a position-dependent mass-tensor for the kinetic energy [1]
$$ T~=~\frac{1}{2}M_{jk}(q)\dot{q}^j\dot{q}^k, \qquad M_{jk}(q)~\equiv~g_{jk}(q), \tag{8.83}$$
where $$(ds)^2~=~g_{jk}(q)~\mathrm{d}q^j ~\mathrm{d}q^k,\tag{8.86}$$
so that
$$ T~=~\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2.\tag{8.87}$$
The [abbreviated action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27s_principle) therefore becomes
$$\begin{align} \int p_k\dot{q}^k ~\mathrm{d}t
~=~&\int 2T ~\mathrm{d}t\cr
~=~&\int \sqrt{2T} ~\mathrm{d}s\cr
~=~&\int \sqrt{2(E-V(q))} ~\mathrm{d}s.\end{align}\tag{8.89}$$
The latter is the sought-for [Jacobi's formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27s_principle#Jacobi%27s_formulation).

References:

1. Herbert Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Section 8.6.